# MongoDB Atlas + prisma + nextjs error: Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `mongo`

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

can't connect to mongodb server on atlas when using env var in mongodb + prisma + nextjs application. getting this error `error: Error validating datasource db: the URL must start with the protocol mongo.` However if I just put the connection string directly into `url` rather than doing `env("DATABASE_URL")`, then it works.

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

.env: `DATABASE_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@somemongodbserver/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

.env.local: `DATABASE_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@somemongodbserver/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Also tried putting this in `next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  env: {
    DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out I already I had `DATABASE_URL` env var set locally for Postgres and it was being used, changing the env var name in the nextjs app fixed the issue

Comment: happened to me, it seems like `npx prisma init` generates the .env file that causes a confuse